# Vibuthi during Sandhyavandanam

Tags: sandhyavandanam, vibuthi

Should I apply Vibuthi like a paste after mixing it with water or just as it is?

I am confused about this, because some say you should only mix it with water while giving pitru tharpanam.

Comment: during pratah kaal use gangajal/water in the evening simpe vibhuti, and in madhyahn with chandan. That is what I have heard from a priest

Comment: After bath, dry vibhuti. Evenings, with water.

Answer (score 0):

***You should ***ALWAYS*** apply vibhuti as a paste with water*** except for vibhuti prasadams from temples, where you can apply directly. So yes, you should apply vibhuti as a paste with water when you're doing sandhyavandanam or any other rituals. And no, pithru tharpanam and the way of applying vibhuti has no correlations as for as I know.

Reference: vedamum panpaadum (Tamil)